# Is my simple user authentication system secure enough?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication, cookies

I've been working on this authentication system for user login and would appreciate some feedback.

My idea is this. Use sessions and one additional cookie. Session cookie and additional cookie work together. In my **Login** class, after i check if the username and password are correct, i call **sessionStart** method and send user's id from database:

```
public function sessionStart($id) {
    session_start();
    $cookieName = "RagingBull";
    $hash = $this->loginHash($id);
    setcookie($cookieName, $hash);
}
```

In my sessionStart method, a **loginHash** method is called. loginHash method creates hash and links together session cookie and additional cookie.

```
public function loginHash($id) {
    $timeStamp              = time();
    $randNumber             = mt_rand(0, 1000);
    $userId                 = $id;
    $_SESSION['timeStamp']  = $timeStamp;
    $_SESSION['randNumber'] = $randNumber;
    $_SESSION['userId']     = $id;
    $userAgent              = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $salt                   = "On the Waterfront";
    $ipFrag                 = substr($this->getUserIP(), 0, 5);
    $forHash                = $timeStamp.$salt.$userId.$ipFrag.$randNumber.$userAgent;
    $hash                   = md5($forHash);
    return $hash;

}
```

For creating a hash value, i use

- timeStamp, which is also saved in session cookie
- randNumber, which is saved in session cookie
- userId, which is saved in session cookie
- userAgent,
- salt, which is saved internaly on the server
- ipFrag, just a fragment of user's IP address.

I save some values in session cookie so that i can use them later when creating hash for comparison. After that, we go back to sessionStart method, and create additional cookie with returned hash value, and then user is logged in.

For authentication, i have **Session** class.

```
class Session {

public function __construct() {

    session_start();
    // checks to see if all the cookies are there
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']) || !isset($_COOKIE['RagingBull'])) {
        header("Location:http://localhost/login.php");
    }

    //create hash for comparison
    $hash = $this->loginHash();

    //if hashes are not the same, redirect
    if(strcmp($hash, $_COOKIE['RagingBull']) !== 0) {
        header("Location:http://localhost/login.php");
    }
}

public function loginHash() {
    $timeStamp  = $_SESSION['timeStamp'];
    $randNumber = $_SESSION['randNumber'];
    $userId         = $_SESSION['userId'];
    $userAgent  = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $salt       = "On the Waterfront";
    $ipFrag     = substr($this->getUserIP(), 0, 5);
    $forHash    =  $timeStamp.$salt.$userId.$ipFrag.$randNumber.$userAgent;
    $hash       = md5($forHash);
    return $hash;
}

public function getUserIP() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}

}
```

To use it, i just create instance of Session class. Then, in constructor, after basic checking, there is creation of hash for comparison, i use the timeStamp, userId and randNumber from session cookie which i saved before, and combine them with user agent and ip fragment from user who requested page.

- Is there any obvious security or logic flaws?
- Is it secure enough?
- Is there too much work for server to do for every page request?
- Is any of this unnecessary?

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing specially not using MD5(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Answers to your questions: 1) Yes. 2) No 3) Most of it is unnecessary 4) Yes

Comment: I could do that. I used password_hash() and password_verify() when storing passwords in database and checking them. But i used just md5 here because it's not about passwords, it's about hash for authentication after login.

Comment: Surley after user has logged in you know they are autenticated because you have an account reference in their session

Comment: @RiggsFolly , well, do you have time to explain me more? I would really appreciate it. I think that this way it would be a little harder for attacker to simply guess valid session session key and additional cookie key trough brute force attacks. Of course i will regenerate session id and cookie key to prevent session fixation.

Comment: Why don't using only (password + salty) hash ?
A good hash function is more than enough if used in the right way.

Comment: Can you summarise in a sentence or two *why* you are creating a second cookie and what its purpose is?

Comment: @deceze Yes. I'm trying to setup a better defence against session hijacking brute force attacks. If someone guess the session cookie value, he could impersonate another user. With second cookie he needs to guess two values at the same time, which is a lot harder.

Comment: So, why don't you simply make the default session value longer? There's no effective difference between using two values or one longer value.

Comment: @deceze Ok, i can do that. But, would it still be secure enough to prevent session hijacking?

Comment: There's a threshold somewhere where a session id becomes *unguessable* (i.e. simply trying random sessions ids to see whether they're active). If you've crossed that threshold, you're fine either way. It doesn't matter whether an attacker would need to guess one long value or two short ones. The threshold is a function of how many concurrent active sessions there can be, how long those stay active, and how often an attacker can try (see: request throttling). If you also protect against outright cookie stealing using HTTPS, you're pretty much good.

Answer (score 0):

This code does a lot of pointless things insecurely.

- Using `mt_rand()` instead of `random_int()`.
- Using `md5($var)` instead of `hash('sha256', $var)`
- Using `md5($password)` instead of `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`
- The "login hash" is entirely meaningless.

If you're trying to do persistent authentication (i.e. "remember me" cookies), [just implement that](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2.1).

If you're trying to protect against session attacks, just use TLS (and ensure your session ID is generated from `/dev/urandom` if you're still on PHP 5) and strict mode. Call `session_regenerate_id(true)` whenever the user logs in or logs out. Done.

The hashing here adds no value, and you're using tools that were not meant for secure authentication.